# Create an empty object of a specified type dynamically

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Using a dataclass to specify a set of environment variables and am trying to keep the dataclass separate from a class that modifies the environment. Passing in an instance of the dataclass and have a `get_env` that determines if those variables are set in the environment. When `os.getenv(field.name.upper(), None)` is called I want `None` to be type as specified in the dataclass. e.g. if `field.type` is a `str` I want something like `os.getenv(field.name.upper(), field.type.__new__(field.type))`

This seems to work but would like to confirm this makes sense or what alternatives to consider?

```
class Env:
  def __init__(self, config: Config):
    self.config = config

  def get_env_dict(self):
    return self.config.to_dict()

  def get_env(self):
    env_dict = self.get_env_dict()
    for field in fields(self.config):
      env_dict[field.name.upper()] = os.getenv(field.name.upper(), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for a dataclass with strings. unsure yet if it will work will all kinds of types.

```
class Env:
  def __init__(self, config: Config):
    self.config = config

  def get_env_dict(self):
    return self.config.to_dict()

  def get_env(self):
    env_dict = self.get_env_dict()
    for field in fields(self.config):
      env_dict[field.name.upper()] = os.getenv(
                                               field.name.upper(), 
                                               field.type.__new__(field.type)
                                              )
```